# Is it possible to execute Jenkins pipeline on an agent, within an agent?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

Specifically, every build I want to hand off to an Agent on a VM and then that agent will send the pipeline to be executed and built entirely within a docker agent

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I entirely understand the question, but yes you can run docker containers "agents" inside an agent.

e.g. here I select a docker capable agent to run the build and then use a Python container to run certain steps

```
pipeline {
    agent { label "docker-capable" }
    options {
        timestamps()
    }
    stages {
        stage("Build the Lambda") { // Runs in container on agent
            agent {
                docker {
                    image "python:3.7"
                    reuseNode true
                    args "-v /usr/bin/zip:/usr/bin/zip"
                }
            }
            environment {
                HOME = "/tmp"
            }
            steps {
                sh "make release"
            }
        }
        stage("Release if Required") { //Runs on agent
            when {
                anyOf {
                    branch 'master'
                    branch 'main'
                }
                not { buildingTag() }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    publishRelease()
                }
            }
        }
```

You can run multiple stages in the same container too e.g.

```
        stage("Python Module Testing") {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image "python:3.7"
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
            environment {
                HOME = "/tmp"
                // Resolve dependencies
                PYTHONPATH = "${WORKSPACE}/package"
            }
            stages {
                stage("Deps") {
                    steps {
                        sh("pip install --user --no-cache-dir pylint flake8")
                    }
                }
                stage("Pylint") {
                    steps {
                        sh("pylint .")
                    }
                }
                stage("Flake8") {
                    steps {
                        sh("flake 8 .")
                    }
                }
```

If you mean can you run some stages on 1 agent and some stages on another agent, then also yes you just dont specify and agent block at the top of the pipeline, but do it for each stage.